# Ошибка urlManager

Tags: yii2

Почему возникает ошибка при использовании urlManager?
Использую шаблон advanced, но почему-то, если подключаю urlManager, то 1 перестает работать. Вернее даже не сам urlManager, а `showScriptName => false`.
Некоторые стили отключаются полностью. Подключаю вот так

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
```

*.htacces*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# Если запрос начинается с /admin, то заменяем на /backend/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

# Если запрос начинается с /api, то заменяем на /rest/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteRule ^api\/?(.*) /rest/web/$1

# Добавляем другой запрос /frontend/web/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|rest/web|admin|api)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

# Если frontend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

# Если api запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rest/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /rest/web/index.php

# Если backend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php
```

Comment: Какая ошибка и о каких стилях идет речь? Вы `.htaccess` настроили?

Comment: @IgorTkachuk добавил .htaccess  вообще 404 ошибку выдет а стили использую AdminLTE при включении 'showScriptName' => false, слитают его стили на ссылки и не работает yiidedug к чему бы это не пойму.